# Admin Session Script

Tags: powershell

In win 10 this following lines run ok, but on windows 8 return:

> **ERROR**: Failed invocation on method because
> [System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] doesn't contains method
> name 'new'.

> **ERROR:** It's not possible call a null expression method

```
$windowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$windowsSecurityPrincipal = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]::new($windowsID)
$adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `::new()` syntax is not supported in older powershell versions.

You have to resort to [New-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-7):

```
$windowsSecurityPrincipal = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal -ArgumentList $windowsID
```